# Search people with Linkedin API

Tags: rest, web-services, linkedin-api, mashup

I noticed that using LinkedIn REST API in my application, i have a strange behaviour

(I'm using Bill Gates as example, but it works like this for every name)

1st REST url request:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id))?first-name=bill&last-name=gates
```

returns 110 results

2nd REST url request:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id))?keywords=bill%20gates
```

returns 0 result

But, according to  API documentation (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api), the second search should return **at least** the 110 "bill gates" returned with the former request, plus eventually other people with some "Bill Gates" string inside their profile ("bill gates" in industry or school name, etc.)

Am i doing something wrong with my second request or what?

**UPDATE:**
Here is a [screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/c23ds2wvx/) of the 2nd request, done by using the [LinkedIn REST Console](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/rest-console/). I would like to know if anyone but me is getting 110 results by replicating that request ...

Comment: Have you tested these queries on the [LinkedIn REST console](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/rest-console/)? They both return 110 results for me. How are you encoding the endpoints? Is it possible that you are feeding in the encoded space, which is being re-encoded, thus turning the `%` into `%25`?

Comment: @PaulMennega I used http://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console, a lot of attempts, and it always returned 0 results. I'm gonna try the console you linked as soon as I get home

Comment: @PaulMennega I used your link, but I'm still getting 0 results, screenshot at http://postimage.org/image/c23ds2wvx/. Did you put the same query string as me in your test?

Comment: Just re-tried it and it worked for me - when you attempt to run the same bill gates query using the same account on LinkedIn.com you get results? Looks like it might be a bug, may want to post it in the [Developer's Forums](https://developer.linkedin.com/forums/rest)

Comment: If I use Linkedin.com web search it works. I have tried with the [support forum](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/search-person-first-name-and-last-name-versus-search-person-keywords) 1 week ago, but nobody answered me. The account I'm using for the test is "basic", but it should work anyway...

Comment: That about using `keywords=bill+gates` instead keywords=bill%20gates?

Comment: @rogal111 I'm sure i tried all the possibilities, "+", " ", "%20"

Comment: Can you provide more detail? This works fine for me - I get 110 and 110. Which does seem weird.

Comment: @selllikesybok Do you have a free Account or a premium account of LinkedIn? I provided the details in here http://postimage.org/image/c23ds2wvx/

Comment: Does this api still works? i am getting error as 403 when i am using user OAuth on  rest console .

Comment: I am sorry @AmitParpiyani I do not know, I have not used that API for over 2 years

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found out the 0 results is related to my network: I don't have any first or second degree connection with someone named Bill Gates.

The keyword search works inside your network, searching for first and second degree connections, meanwhile the first-name/last-name search works outside it, so my results are not 0 with the latter.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your reply until today, but yes, this is what I thought would be the case. Depends on the network of the authenticated user. Non-API LinkedIn search is something I do multiple times per day. Didn't know about the API test tools, though, so that's a neat tip.