# Linkedin official "search people" API

Tags: api, rest, search, linkedin-api, profile

My company needs to develop an app where we need to make use of the searching the profile BY EMAIL ADDRESS.

there are several questions and/or other resources regarding the "search api" on the linkedin API. Lots of them contain broken links or outdated information.
E.g.
[Linkedin rest api to search people with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458638/linkedin-rest-api-to-search-people-with-name)
[Search people with Linkedin API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191798/search-people-with-linkedin-api)
[What are the steps to use linkedin people search api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230460/what-are-the-steps-to-use-linkedin-people-search-api)
http://www.programmableweb.com/api/linkedin-people-search

Of course, I started here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

To my understanding, there was a change in the API in 2015, which left basic profile for the public to use, the availabiliy of the rest went under the Partnership Programs.

Is the search API available under all of the listed profiles? Does anyone of you use it these days? (mid-2016)?